# Change thread priority - Unity 3d

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

So I am using threading in my application. I wanted to benchmark parts of my code, and I saw that the code runs significantly faster on the main thread - 2-3 times faster.

I wanted to tweak the thread priority of the threads i am creating, but for some reason the priority stays the same - lowest always.

Code:

```
public static void RunTest()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Fun);

        Debug.Log("thread.Priority before change: " + thread.Priority);

        thread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Normal;

        Debug.Log("thread.Priority after change:" + thread.Priority);

        thread.Start();
    }

    static void Fun()
    {
        Debug.Log("I am running on a separate thread!");
        Debug.Log("Current thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Priority);
    }
```

I always get "lowest" - in all 3 cases.

How can i change the thread priority in unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity uses the version of Mono that did not implement *Thread Priority*.

It is now implemented in [Mono 4.4](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.4.0/#implement-thread-priority-setting) but that's not the version of Mono Unity is using. Until they upgrade their Mono version to this version, this simply won't work.